# Showing local tasks in toolbar with hook_toolbar: caching problem

Tags: 8, caching, toolbar

I'm creating a module using the toolbar api showing all administrative functions in a more compact toolbar. I'm having "cache" troubles showing the local tasks in the toolbar... How can I keep these items outside the toolbar cache?

In my custom module I use hook_toolbar to add the local tasks

```
/**
 * Implements hook_toolbar().
 */
function compact_toolbar_toolbar() {

    $items = [];
    ...

    $tasks = _compact_toolbar_local_tasks();
    $items = array_merge($items,$tasks);

    return $items;
}
```

And a function to generate the toolbar local tasks...

```
/**
 * Create local tasks toolbar items
 */
function _compact_toolbar_local_tasks() {

    $items = [];
    $route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
    $manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.local_task');
    $primary = $manager->getLocalTasks($route, 0);

    foreach($primary['tabs'] as $key => $tab) {

        // add toolbar tab
        $items[$key] = [
            '#type' => 'toolbar_item',
            '#cache' => [ // Can I overrule the toolbar cache here?
                'max-age' => 0, 
            ],
            'tab' => [
                '#type' => 'link',
                '#title' => $tab['#link']['title'],
                '#url' => $tab['#link']['url'],
                '#access' => $tab['#access'],
                '#attributes' => [
                    'title' => $tab['#link']['title'],
                ],
            ],
            '#weight' => $tab['#weight'],
        ];

        // check if task is active
        if($tab['#active']) {
            $items[$key]['tab']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'is-active';
        }

        // get secondary tabs for each primary tab
        $route = $items[$key]['tab']['#url']->getRouteName();
        $secondary = $manager->getLocalTasks($route, 1);

        // get secondary tabs as tray
        if (!empty($secondary['tabs'])) {

            $links = [];
            $items[$key]['tab']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'toolbar-parent'; 

            // create renderable array of secondary links
            foreach ($secondary['tabs'] as $skey => $stab) {
                $sname = substr($skey, strrpos($key, '.') + 1);
                $links[$sname] = [
                    'type' => 'link',
                    'title' => $stab['#link']['title'],
                    'url' => $stab['#link']['url'],
                ];
            }

            // add tray with secondary tasks
            $items[$key]['tray'] = [
                '#heading' => t('Secondary tasks'),
                'toolbar_secondary_tasks' => [
                    '#theme' => 'links__toolbar',
                    '#links' => $links,
                    '#attributes' => ['class' => ['toolbar-menu']],
                ],
            ];

        }

    }

    return $items;
}
```

When I disable the cache in hook_page_top in core/modules/toolbar/toolbar.module everything works like a charm. Otherwise my custom items won't follow the current page...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_top().
 *
 * Add admin toolbar to the top of the page automatically.
 */
function toolbar_page_top(array &$page_top) {
  $page_top['toolbar'] = array(
    '#type' => 'toolbar',
    '#access' => \Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('access toolbar'),
    /*
    '#cache' => [
      'keys' => ['toolbar'],
      'contexts' => ['user.permissions'],
    ],
    */
  );
}
```

Can I overrule the toolbar cache by using the #cache array in my custom toolbar items? Which tags/context should I use?

This is how the toolbar looks like with my compact_toolbar module enabled... (but toolbar cache disabled) I really like the result! - I also made the menu behave like a simple dropdown menu and added a "content menu" to quickly add new content...

[image: Compact toolbar example]

Comment: I want this toolbar! It's beautiful, but I can't find any releases for compact_toolbar. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"The toolbar is a container for administrative and site-global interactive components."

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!toolbar!toolbar.api.php/function/hook_toolbar/8.2.x

That would indicate that the toolbar is not the solution you are looking for as the more contextual tabs are not site global but page specific.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this, the following worked for me:

```
'#cache' => [
   'contexts' => [
     'url.path',
   ],
 ],
```

The key is to look at the available [cache contexts](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts), in this case, setting by URL.

So example including above would be:

```
 $items[$key]['tray'] = [
 '#heading' => t('Secondary tasks'),
 'toolbar_secondary_tasks' => [
   '#theme' => 'links__toolbar',
   '#links' => $links,
   '#attributes' => ['class' => ['toolbar-menu']],
 ],
 '#cache' => [
   'contexts' => [
    'url.path',
   ],
 ],
```

];