# add link to edit content in admin top bar

Tags: 8

I'm theming a web site that I haven’t created and I‘ve noticed this useful link placed in admin top bar (see screen shot) :

[image]

It provides link to edit / delete content.

How can I place this link on other website ?

I use Admin Toolbar + Adminimal Admin Toolbar with Adminimal 8.

Actually, I have the native menu and it is quite disturbing when you work on theming because it is placed inside content.

[image]

Comment: Something along these lines: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196523/showing-local-tasks-in-toolbar-with-hook-toolbar-caching-problem/215638

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the "shortcuts" menu tab which comes natively in a D8 installation but if you're looking to add your own custom shortcut menu (& menu items) you might want to look into the hook_toolbar: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!toolbar!toolbar.api.php/function/hook_toolbar/8.2.x

You can build a quick custom module to establish your own links and configurations. Hope I answered your question!